# Create API layer over database

Tags: database, oracle, api, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an on premise oracle database.  Can I use anything on AWS e.g. API Gateway to query the database and expose the results via API?  I know I could do API Gateway -> Lambda -> Oracle DB where the code in the Lambda function would query the database (assuming query takes less than 5 mins).  Are there any other easy options that would be serverless and with minimal amount of code?

Basically I would like to find the simplest way to create an API layer over the top of an existing on premise oracle database so that applications (hosted on AWS) can access this data without connecting directly to the database.  Does AWS provide anything out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be an out of the box way provided by AWS to connect API Gateway to your on premise Oracle DB. So basically the way you provided (API Gateway->Lambda->Oracle) should be the way to go.

Now the question is if you want to connect to your Oracle directly or if your want to create a replication of your database in RDS and create a synch mechanism between RDS and your on premise Oracle DB to keep the DB highly responsive and available (in case of network failure between AWS and your local network). I think that depends on how you access your DB on premise.

If your won't create an replica in RDS you should at least use a VPN connection to your local network to keep data transfer from on premise Oracle to AWS RDS secure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it is possible to use AWS Lambda and expose the API through API
   Gateway. But that is the easy part.
2. The tough part is to get your On-Premise database connected to AWS
   infrastructure. If you have an on premise database, and you are
   working in a large enterprise, you will need to get through a lot of
   approvals to setup a VPN or a AWS Direct Connect.
3. The ideal solution is to use AWS Direct Connect to extend your
   corporate infrastructure to connect to AWS and then use Lambda to
   connect to the DB.
4. Also there is no out of the box solution in AWS to connect to
   OracleDB. At the most, you can wrap all business logic in Stored
   Procedures, and execute them in the lambda function. You can always
   use the JDBC from Lambda to connect and query your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from AWS Marketplace https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01MU8W71L